# Gmail-label-like behavior for Outlook mail folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

At work, I have to use mail via Outlook. I'm not fond of the way my Outlook mail can only be reside in one folder. I miss Gmail lable a lot while using Outlook.

Is there any way to turn Outlook folder to be a label so that one mail can appear in many folder at a time (but they are one mail instance only).

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with 'categories'.  By default the categories in Outlook are just colors, but this can be changed.  If you right click on a message, select the 'Categorize->All Categories...' menu item.  The 'Color Categories' dialog will open which allows you to create new, rename, or delete categories.

If you then add 'CATEGORIES' as a column in the mailbox view you can right click and assign a category to the message.  Multiple categories can be assigned to each message, which should give you the functionality that you want.

Comment: This won't give the functionality Nam wants. You can't make the category list behave in a folder-like manner.

Comment: The answers already given here are missing an important step.  Once you have your categories, you can use Outlook's "Search Folders" to create a virtual folder that finds everything with a given category.

So if you have a certain mail item that's categorized as both "Project A" and "Client X" and you set up search folders for both categories, the same email will show up in both.

Answer (score 5):

No way. Outlook operates with folders.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually rather easy. As explained above it is called Categories in Outlook. There is a small trick to it though. You only see a very small colored square for the category, in order to fix this simple resize the category column. Now you will see the text also, and then final step you can right-click this column, or the categorize column at the top (the colored square with the small down arrow) and rename your categories/labels. See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: But you can have an almost unlimited number of google labels, whereas only a very small number of Outlook categories.

Comment: You can add lots of categories, just limited to 25 colors.